# need to pass data from one page to other page using only one controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, code

I have 2 VF pages
Pag1

```
<apex:page controller="controller1" >
    <apex:form>
        Enter Text<apex:inputText value="{!input1}" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!show}" />
        <apex:outputText value="{!showf}"></apex:outputText>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>`
```

Page 2

```
<apex:page controller="controller1" >
    <apex:outputText value="{!showf}"></apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class Controller1 {
    public string input1{get;set;}
    public string  showf{get;set;}
    public Controller1(){
         showf = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('showf');
    }
    public void show(){
        showf=input1+'get the Parameter';
    }
}
```

I just want to show the input1 into other page(page2)

Answer (score 0):

You have a really nice name.

Why are you using the same controller? It can be confusing.

With Apex, you can open a page and add parameters to this page. Here's the solution for your code:

```
public PageReference show(){
   PageReference page2 = Page.Page2; //Here's the name of your second page
   page2.getParameters().put('showf', showf);
   page2.setRedirect(true);
   return page2;
}
```

**Update**

And you have to change your page 1 to link the showf variable to the input:

```
<apex:page controller="controller1" >
    <apex:form>
        Enter Text<apex:inputText value="{!showf}" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!show}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: do i need to change in vf Page2?.its coming blank when i am clicking to button in vf page1

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick solution,but it showing value in URL.I need to display the value into Page2

Comment: If your page 2 contains the code you provided it must shows the value in the page.

Comment: Thanks.I chnaged the controller as below                                                   public PageReference show(){
   PageReference nextpage =  new PageReference('/apex/Page2');

   return nextpage;

Comment: Its working now